# Angular 2 component *ngFor template parse error

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have the following error from angular 2:

```
EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token . at column 26 in [ngFor let button of modal.buttons] in ModalComponent@11:22 ("">
                        <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal"
                          [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let button of modal.buttons"
                          [ngClass]="button.classes"
                   "): ModalComponent@11:22
```

This is my code:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {NgFor, NgClass} from 'angular2/common';

import {EventService} from '../services/event.service';

interface Button {
  text: string;
  classes: Array<string>;
  clicked: Function;
}

interface Modal {
  title: string;
  text: string;
  buttons: Array<Button>;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'modal',
  template:  `<div *ngIf="modal" class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">{{modal.title}}</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body" [innerHTML]="modal.text"></div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal"
                      *ngFor="let button of modal.buttons"
                      [ngClass]="button.classes"
                    >{{button.text}}</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>`,
  directives: [NgFor, NgClass]
})
export class ModalComponent {
  modalElement: HTMLElement;
  modal: Modal = [...];

  [...]

}
```

I try to generate a modal component, without the buttons it works fine.
Why is this wrong? Why cant angular iterate over an object child array?
I am searching for hours, please help

Comment: I tried to use elvis operator ( ? ), but does not work, too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In angular2.rc1 syntax of *ngFor has changed, from `*ngFor="#item in items"` to `*ngFor="let item in items"`;

You are using new syntax, but have old version of angular2. I supposed it based on your imports (you are referencing to 'angular2/...', instead of '@angular/...').

Try old syntax or update to new version of angular.

Comment: The old syntax das not work and @angular does not work either

Comment: i use 2.0.0-beta.7

Comment: Is it impossible to use rc1? do you have some other dependencies? beta.7 is very old, do not recommend to spend time on it.

Comment: system-config.js also needs to be configured properly. can you provide more details on error? what it say for @angular?..

Comment: That error is not related to ngFor, at first you need to setup working environment of angular2, after, *ngFor will work.

Comment: I update the hole angular project and know it works, thx a lot

Comment: you welcome :) - It is cool framework, I love it. Also watch for development of angular2-cli (https://cli.angular.io/). It has usefull commands to simplify creation of environment, build, test, etc.

Comment: The latest syntax for *ngFor (rc6) is `*ngFor="let item of items"`

Comment: For final version you have to use:    *ngFor="let item of items"

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is correct for *ngFor, however, the "template" tag's format is slightly different.

Before RC0 and RC1:

```
<template ngFor #team [ngForOf]="teams">
```

After RCx:

```
<template ngFor let-team [ngForOf]="teams">
```

Where team is the "for of" variable iterated through teams.  The # is still used!  If you want access to an html component:

```
<input #numberInput step="0.1" type="number">
```

Notice nothing has changed here.  The way to think about this is; 'let' is used for variables of data; '#' is used to get access to html components.

For further change details, please always refer first to:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 0):

***ngFor="let item in items";**

Try like this still not work means  please ensure the

**import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';**

are injected in module.ts or not this also done meas

ensure all given element are correct with spelling and

corresponding close tag are present